# SharePoint custom search results page

Tags: search, search-results

I am trying to create a custom search results page as I want to display the custom master page on the results page, but keep the system master page as seattle.master.

I created a page called searchresults.aspx on the site, and modified the search settings results to point to this page whenever a search occurs. Now it works that when users are searching for something, they're redirected to this page, BUT, no results.

The URL that appears on the searchresults.aspx is ?k=mysearch, but no results appear. The type of webpart on that page is search results webpart. How do I make it to display results? If I open webpart properties and test the query, I can see results, but when I am redirected to the page when I do the search, it doesn't show results. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you configures search results webpart to take query from URL ? In the Web Part tool pane, in the Search Criteria section, click Change query.
On the keyboard filter, select the Value of a parameter from URL.

Comment: Thank you, where do I find criteria section?